# How to find if a GeoCoordinate point is within boundaries

Tags: c#, maps, coordinates

I have a list of points (actually shops coordinates) and I need to determine if they lay within certain boundaries.

In C# I know how to create a point from lat&lng

```
var point = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
```

But how can I check if that point is contained in the rectangle defined by those other two points:

```
    var swPoint = new GeoCoordinate(bounds.swlat, bounds.swlng);
    var nePoint = new GeoCoordinate(bounds.nelat, bounds.nelng);
```

Is there any class method I can use?

Comment: Can't you just check that your point's lat/long are >= the sw point's lat/long and <= the ne point's lat/long?

Comment: We need more details.  Are you using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.aspx ?

Comment: Yes I am using System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate, but if that is not the right solution I can use something else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.aspx

You will have to write your own method to make this check.  You may want to make it an extension method (Lot's of resources available on Extension Methods online.)

Then it is almost as simple as

```
public static Boolean isWithin(this GeoCoordinate pt, GeoCoordinate sw, GeoCoordinate ne)
{
   return pt.Latitude >= sw.Latitude &&
          pt.Latitude <= ne.Latitude &&
          pt.Longitude >= sw.Longitude &&
          pt.Longitude <= ne.Longitude
}
```

There is one corner case to consider.  The above method will fail if the box defined by sw, ne crosses the 180-degree Longitude.  So additional code will have to be written to cover that case, thus slowing the performance of the method.

Comment: Your solution is not considering when crossing the equator I think, if the boundaries span across equator wouldn't work.

Comment: Actually crossing the equator is not a problem for the given solution since latitudes south of the equator are simply negative numbers.  Only crossing the 180-longitude line requires more code.

Comment: @Max Favilli But I /was/ wrong in saying that there is only one corner case.  If your lat/long inclusion box covers one of the poles, then that needs yet another check.  But, interestingly, that case can not be represented with just passing in two corners, so it is not a big concern unless you know you need to account for it.  If you need to have a box that can contain poles you will need to gather the two points into a class and add a Boolean spansPole; member.

Comment: Thanks! I am building a store locator so I don't I need to care about poles.

Comment: That's one advantage of having the 180 degree line in a big ocean. Very few stores are located there.

Comment: There is not any road crossing the datum limit (180 deg).

Comment: Working with https://github.com/scottschluer/geolocation library. private bool isWithin(Geolocation.Coordinate pt, Geolocation.Coordinate sw, Geolocation.Coordinate ne){}